# 3rd level Thief's damage

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, rogue, thief

I'm a player, not a DM.

A 3rd-level Thief with shortbow, when his mates are fighting against foes, uses Stealth by bonus action and so he shot the enemy two times (advantage), he hit one of the target and he rolls 3d6 damage +6. Why?

- 1d6 for the bow
- 1d6 for the stealth (?) and..
- 1d6 for what?
- and at the end +4 for Strength/Dexterity bonus and +2 for proficiency bonus?

If all of this is correct, at 3rd level, a Thief does more damage than a 3rd-level Paladin – is that correct?

Comment: I think that we need more details to provide a proper answer: for example, the abilities scores, any feat the char has, if they are using a magic weapon, et cetera. The 3d6 is pretty clear, it is the +6 that looks too large for me. Moreover, a possible answer will cover the fact that having advantage does not means that they can shoot twice.

Comment: Is it possible for you to ask the player?

Comment: do you mean "shortbow" (which i'm assuming based on the 1d6 damage), or "light crossbow"? Because there's no such thing in 5e as "short crossbow" and will just confuse people, i'm gonna edit but feel free to roll back if that's not what you meant

Comment: " uses Stealth by bonus action" Note that _Stealth_ is a skill. There's no way to "use" it, it's just something that applies to skill checks. Do you mean they use the _Hide_ action? Note that that's not something you can just "do", hiding requires you to prevent your opponents from being able to see you (e.g. being behind a corner or wall, in darkness or fog, or being invisible).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rogues can do Sneak Attack damage once per turn when they attack with advantage (or when they attack someone already in melee combat with someone else but that doesn't apply here).

On 3rd level this extra damage is 2d6, so assuming that you meant "hand crossbow" or "shortbow" as the weapon (there's no such thing as short crossbow in the standard equipment list), we've got 1d6 (weapon base damage) + 2d6 (sneak attack damage)

You can then add your Dexterity bonus to the damage (+4) but **you can't add the proficiency bonus to the damage**. So the correct damage is 3d6+4.

*(It's also worth noting that **rogues don't get an extra attack**, not even from bonus actions, unless they are using two weapons, which is not very realistic with bows.)*

Is this more than the paladin's damage?

Well, yes and no.

Paladins will typically fight with more damaging weapons, so let's assume a longsword in one hand, that's 1d8 damage. With a Strength bonus of +4, the total damage is thus 1d8+4.

However paladins also have the Divine Smite feature, which means they can use one of their spell slots to add 2d8 radiant type damage to their hits. So in total that's 3d8+4, which is more.

Of course in both cases there are limitations: a rogue has to have advantage to be able to apply sneak attack while a paladin has a limited number of spell slots they can use (3 at 3rd level), once they run out of them, they can't apply Divine Smite damage to their attacks until after the next long rest.

So overall they're different but at this level neither is wildly more powerful than the other.

Comment: I think that it is worth to explain what advantage means, and what does not mean (in this case, attacking twice).

Comment: Given OP's use of '3th level', it is likely they are not a native English speaker.  'Short crossbow' may be their literal translation for whatever their ruleset uses for hand crossbow or shortbow.

Comment: Sorry for the "short crossbow". biziclop you have centered the question! Normally we fight orc gangs so the Paladin early finish the Divine Smith instead the Rogue bonus for Sneak Attack still exists at the end of the day.

Comment: @alemayo That is true, but Sneak Attack requires the rogue to stay undetected, so it's not very useful for example when the enemies ambush you.

Comment: @biziclop That is true, but after 1 or 2 round the Thief go Sneak again. At the end of the day the total Thief damage overwhelm the total Paladin damage. That's why the team strategy work for the best of the team (and Rogue too), that's another true too!

Comment: @biziclop SNeak Attack doesn't require the rogue to stay undetected, why do you think that?

Comment: @biziclop Sneak attack requires using a finesse or a ranged weapon and advantage on the attack roll. And moreover, from the rules, "You don’t need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn’t incapacitated, and you don’t have disadvantage on the attack roll."

Comment: @NautArchisonstrike I've covered the rules in my answer but in practice, with ranged weapons, it usually boils down to either staying undetected, or somehow unreachable. Otherwise someone will just step up to you and start punching you.

Comment: @biziclop: That's the nice thing about having allies adjacent to the enemy – they can't move away from your allies toward you without provoking opportunity attacks from your allies.

Comment: To be fair, the rogue probably will do more damage than a paladin.  This is just the difference between a front line character and a damage dealer.  Rogues shine when they have a team to help draw advantage from.